# How to refresh an Excel table filled with data from a MYSQL Database

Tags: mysql, database, excel, mysql-workbench

So I want to refresh my Excel table every so often from a MYSQL database that gets new rows every so often.

I have been able to import the Database into my Excel table, but then I cannot figure out a way to update that table with new data added to the MYSQL Database.

- To be able to connect to my MYSQL Database I use the MYSQL software MYSQL for Excel - Version 1.2.1

Any one have an idea how or if it is something that can be done ?

Comment: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/create-edit-and-manage-connections-to-external-data-HA010167227.aspx

Comment: link (thru a data connection) instead of import

Comment: @PA. Thanks I just tried this and it worked great :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Link your data (using a Data Connection) instead of importing your data.